# ¿Cómo puedo testear este codigo en junit4 y java 8?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, java-8, junit

Estoy intentando testear este codigo por completo en junit 4 y java 8(no puedo mejorar la version)

La cosa es, no puedo usar en esta version el **@mockbean** o el **@autowired**, asi que, ¿Cual es la mejor opción para testear si no puedo mejorar la version?

Codigo:

```
public class DaoHibernate extends BaseDaoHibernate implements Dao {

private static final String ID_CD_QUERY_PARAM = "idCD";
private static final String IDPAIS_QUERY_PARAM = "idPais";
/**
 * Instancia del logger
 */
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DaoHibernate.class);
private static final SimpleDateFormat SDF = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");



public List<Combo> getThingsByCamion (Integer idCD, Date fDesde,Date fHasta, Integer idPais,String idReferenciaTransporte){
    try {
        List<Combo> things = new ArrayList<Combo>();

        if (idCD != null) {

            final StringBuilder hqlQueryThings = new StringBuilder();

            hqlQueryThings.append("SELECT DISTINCT ");
            hqlQueryThings.append(" ao.referencia ");
            hqlQueryThings.append(" FROM ");
            hqlQueryThings.append(" almacen.agrupacion_operativa ao, ");
            hqlQueryThings.append(" almacen.Detalle_Agrupacion_Operativa dao, ");
            hqlQueryThings.append(" almacen.detalle_envio_exportacion dee, ");
            hqlQueryThings.append(" almacen.seguimiento_bulto sb ");

            if(idPais!=null ){
                hqlQueryPallet.append(" INNER JOIN MAESTROS.LOCALIZACION LOC ON LOC.ID_LOCALIZACION = sb.id_localizacion_destino ")
                .append(" AND LOC.ID_PAIS = :idPais ");
            }

            hqlQueryThings.append(" WHERE ");
            hqlQueryThings.append(" ao.id_agrupacion_operativa = dao.id_agrupacion_operativa AND ");
            hqlQueryThings.append(" sb.id_localizacion_origen = :idCD AND ");
            hqlQueryThings.append(" dee.id_bulto = dao.id_bulto  ");

            if(idReferenciaTransporte!=null ){
                hqlQueryPallet.append("  AND dee.referencia_transporte = :idReferenciaTransporte ");
            }
            if(fDesde!=null && fHasta!=null){
                hqlQueryThings.append("  AND SB.Fecha_Expedicion >= :fDesde AND ");
                hqlQueryThings.append("  SB.Fecha_Expedicion <= :fHasta ");
            }

            hqlQueryThings.append(" WITH UR ");
            final Query queryThing = getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession()
            .createSQLQuery(hqlQueryPallet.toString());
            if (idPais != null) {
                queryThing.setInteger(IDPAIS_QUERY_PARAM, idPais);
            }
            if (idReferenciaTransporte != null) {
                queryThing.setString("idReferenciaTransporte", idReferenciaTransporte);
            }
            queryThing.setInteger(ID_CD_QUERY_PARAM, idCD);
            queryThing.setDate("fDesde", fDesde);
            queryThing.setDate("fHasta", fHasta);

            final List<String> result = (List<String>) queryThing.list();

            if (result != null) {

                for(String obj : result){
                    Combos c = new Combos();
                    c.setKey(obj);
                    c.setValue(obj);

                    pallets.add(c);
                }
            }
        }
        LOGGER.debug("Fin getThingsByCamion");
        return pallets;
    } catch (final RuntimeException recep) {
        LOGGER.error("Errorejecutando getThings", recep);
        throw recep;
    }
}
```

Cuando llego a la linea:
`final Query queryThing = getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession() .createSQLQuery(hqlQueryPallet.toString());`

solo me dice NullpointerException porque básicamente no me encuentra la sesión.

El test:

```
public class DaoHibernateTests {

private static final String ORIGEN = "Origen";
private static final String MATRICULA = "Matricula";
private static final String CODIGO_ENVIO = "Envio";

private static final String PLATAFORMA = "Plataforma 1";
private static final Integer ID_PLATAFORMA = 1;

/** The sdf. */
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

private DaoHibernate daoHibernate;
private Date fechaEnvio;

@Before
public void setUp() throws ParseException {

    fechaEnvio = sdf.parse("01-01-2021");

    daoHibernate = new DaoHibernate();
}

@Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
public void buscarMercanciaEntradaTestError1() {
    List<Combo> getThingsByCamion = daoHibernate.getThingsByCamion(1, fechaEnvio,fechaEnvio, 1,CODIGO_ENVIO);

    Assert.assertEquals(1, getThingsByCamion.size());
}
```

POM: Dependencies para el testing:

```
<java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <junit.version>4.4</junit.version>    

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
```

Que necesitaria hacer?

Saludos!

Comment: Puedes colocar el código del método `getHibernateTemplate()` para poder como esta creando la session.

Comment: @RobertoEMoran a que te refieres exactamente? Yo cuando lo declaro en el test, no me lo encuentra. Me sale como fallo en el eclipse. Entonces a que te refeies de colocar el código?